# Javascript regex to match beginning and end of CSS comment

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I need to un-comment some CSS via jQuery and Regex, here's what I have so far:

`$('style').html($('style').html().replace('/*','').replace('*/',''))`

The problem is, that's two replace methods which isn't optimal for performance. Is it possible to write a regex that matches and removes both the beginning and end comment strings?

**How can I write this entire line with the best performance possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
.replace(/(\/\*|\*\/)/g,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex pattern `(\/\*[\w\'\s\r\n\*]*\*\/)`

have a preview here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?338e0

Comment: In this case, you should capture the content inside the comment rather than the whole thing (since the OP wants to uncomment).

Answer (score 0):

if you want remove all comment try this:

```
replace(/\/\*[^\/\*]+\*\//g,'')
```

if you just want remove "*" and "*\" try Prodigy